# 32 bit audio on Windows?

Tags: audio, 32-bit, openal

I would like to play 32 bit audio from my computer. Is this possible? I know about "AL_EXT_FLOAT32" extension, but does any hardware/windows even support this? And if there is support for it, will it just be reconverted and played as 16 bit audio?

Is it possible to play 32 bit audio from a PC with consumer hardware?

Comment: As far as I know, it's a hardware thing. Most audio cards can play at most 24-bit audio. You might be able to Re-sample it to 24. 32-bit doesn't have much practical use, either - the dynamic range of 24 is more than broad enough. I'd say you should re-consider using 32-bit at all.

Comment: Is there any 24 bit support in OpenAL? Then only extension higher than 16 I could find was AL_EXT_FLOAT32. And all computers I have tried report that AL_EXT_FLOAT32 is not supported.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, most consumer hardware only supports 16-bit audio output. Some of the premium sound devices sometimes support up to 24-bit. Most digital audio systems support 16 and 24-bit PCM steams. I have not seen consumer devices which support 32-bit PCM.
Most likely windows will just scale it down or, with some devices, will crash the sound driver (remember some Sound-Blasters on XP).

Many music formats can be stored in (normalized) 32-bit floats, and will quite possibly be processed by OpenAL or Operating system's audio mixer in 32-bit floats. The mixer then sends the data to the driver, which is usually 16-bit.

I don't know OpenAL, but I think that format is about the input audio format (or the internal mixer?), not the audio output it will produce?
That, or it supports high-end professional equipment?